# Is the Samsung Health App as a whole ending? Or is it just the Together Community tab/program?

Tags: applications, samsung

> We regret to inform you that the Together Community(BETA) service will no longer be available as of 1 July 2020.

https://www.reddit.com/r/samsung/comments/hevmxm/samsung_health_app_ending_the_together_community/

https://content.samsungknowledge.com/notices/46/en-US/en_US.html

Question: This refers to the 'together' tab of the samsung health app and not the whole of the samsung health app right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samsung Health is still alive so yeah the together tab I guess.